# How to scan user input to confirm performing the DELETE operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, request-mapping

I am learning how use spring-boot and to create webservices. I created some examples and now i think i understand how it works. however, the following point i could not find out how to 
develop or to create as I did not find examples in google.

The code belwo shows how I developed the remove operation using http method DELETE.
the question is, how the below code should be developed so that user can be asked if he indeed wants to perform the deletion operation? and based on his choice the DELETE operation 
should be performed or not.

**code**:

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/{idx}", 
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Product> doRemove(@Validated @Size(min = 0) @PathVariable(required = true) int idx,
        Model model) {

    Product productToRemove = productService.getProductFromListByIdx(idx);
    if (productToRemove == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    model.addAttribute(RemoveProductPageController.sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName, productToRemove);
    productService.removeProdcutFromListBxIdx(idx);
    return new ResponseEntity<Product>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I feel like this should be done on the FE, not in your actual request code

Comment: @smac89 what is FE

Comment: FE means front end. So the web facing part of your application - the one the user directly interacts with. This could be some sort of form, react, vue, simple html page, etc and when the user tries to delete something, you can have a dialog box /popup box that asks them to confirm, and finally this request is sent to your BE (backend) which is where your above method handles the delete request. Your server/spring app should not be the one asking the user if they are sure they want to delete because that's just wasted bandwidth and can easily be abused

Answer (score 0):

Backend service should not do such thing. You should handle the confirm process on your frontend(UI) by providing a dialog. Only if the user click the confirm button(or something else), it will call DELETE api.

In software development, backend service(such as Spring boot) should only provide API services, and for user interaction or user interfaces logic should be implement in frontend.